# how can i set the background image of mail controller

Tags: iphone, ipad

How we set the background of mail composer through code in iphone, ipad 
  if any one have any idea plz suggess me 
 just i want to set my splash screen on the background of mail controller view .

Answer (score 1):

It has been clearly mentioned in the Apple doc's that you should not customize that view.

**Important**: The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application. In addition, after presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored. Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the interface.

From, [Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)